# "who" command - How to show IP address

Tags: command-line

I would like to know if there is an option to get the IP address of loged users with `who` command?

When I type `who` I get this:

> wolfy@wolfy-server:~$ who
>
> wolfy    pts/0        2012-06-01 09:43 (tzu-23-764-657.sta.als.some.net)

I would like to replace "tzu-23-764-657.sta.als.some.net" with a real IP address, like in "last" command:

> wolfy@wolfy-server:~$ last -i
>
> wolfy    pts/0        123.123.123.123  Fri Jun  1 09:43   still logged in

I did not find any options to do that... do you know a way to do this... maybe a different command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--ips` switch.

To quote the manual:

> `--ips`
>
> Print  ips  instead  of  hostnames. With `--lookup`, canonicalizes based
>   on stored IP, if available, rather than stored hostname.

Comment: For the record, the `--ips` support was added by Debian in 2006, it's not supported by "standard" coreutils